# I am getting JAVA_HOME not set error on azure python webapp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, java-home

i am trying to install jdk on python webapp so that I can use Sparksession in my python code. But jdk gets installed in /usr/lib directory instead of /home directory and anything outside /home directory does not persist. That is why even if I use Java tool installer and try to install jdk through command line in azure pipeline, still i get JAVA_HOME not set error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify any OS level as App Service exists in a sandbox; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality. Every app service comes preconfigured with various SDKs. If your app is hosted in a Windows app service, you can run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the CMD/Powershell to see what the version is.

[image]

If the available version is lower than what you need, I suggest switching to [Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container?pivots=container-windows) where you can install the JDK you need on your image.

Comment: my webapp is hosted on linux. and when i try echo $java_home, it returns empty. The problem is jdk needs to be installed inside /home and I don't know how to do that because it always get installed by default in /usr/lib which is outside /home

Comment: If your app is hosted in Linux, then a base image is being pulled down from mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/python:latest. To get a general idea of these images, check out https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/tree/master/doc#contents. But I don't think you can modify during deployment. I suggest creating your own image with Java configured